# How to specify the port to expose and custom argument from the command line

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I did an application in Spring Boot and I'm trying to do a Dockerfile with environment variables to specify the port to expose and any custom arguments from the command line.

```
# defines a source container image to build upon
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# adding a volume to save the logs
VOLUME /tmp

# copy a local file into the container
COPY build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar

# environment variable
ENV SERVER_PORT 0
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""

# the app will listen on port ####
EXPOSE ${SERVER_PORT}

# tells Docker what it should execute when you run that container
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c","java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar"]
```

When I run:

```
docker run -d JAVA_OPTS=-Dserver.port=2020 SERVER_PORT=2020 -p 8080:2020 my-good-app
```

Error:

> docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.

I would like to do this from the command line:

1. Specify the port to expose by the container
2. Specify the port that my application will use when it runs

To accomplish this, as my command above, I have tried:

1. SERVER_PORT=2020 (The port to expose by the container)
2. JAVA_OPTS=-Dserver.port=2020 (The port that my application will use when it runs)

My goal is to specify the port that the container will expose from the command line, also I would like to pass any custom argument/command from the command line to edit my Spring Boot application behavior, in this case, change it's port when it runs to match the port expose by the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to customize this.  Since each container runs in an isolated network space, it's not a problem to have multiple containers each listening on the same port, just so long as when you publish those ports you use different host ports.

Spring Boot by default listens on port 8080, so just hard-code that in your Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
# No need to have an anonymous volume on /tmp
# Don't need to customize port or provide empty default variable
# Do expose default port (mostly for documentation)
EXPOSE 8080
# Provide default command to run (Docker provides `sh -c`)
CMD java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

When you go to run it, you can specify an arbitrary host port, even if you run multiple copies of the container.  Make sure the second `-p` port number matches what the container is actually listening on.

```sh
docker run -d --name app1 -p 8080:8080 my-good-app
docker run -d --name app2 -p 8081:8080 my-good-app
```

On modern Docker, "expose" as a verb means almost nothing, and there's no harm in having a port exposed with nothing listening on it.  If you really needed a different container-side port, and you really needed it exposed, in principle you could still set these options:

```
docker run -d --name app3 \
  -e JAVA_OPTS=-Dserver.port=2020 \
  --expose 2020 \
  -p 8082:2020 \
  my-good-app
```

In the `docker run` command you show, make sure to specify a `-e` option before each environment variable value you set (you do not have a `-e` before `SERVER_PORT`, which leads to your error).  Also remember that most of the Dockerfile is completely processed before anything in the `docker run` command is considered; no matter what `-e SERVER_PORT=...` you set at run time, the image will always have `EXPOSE 0`.  You could use [build arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) to specify this at compile time, but there's not a lot of value in doing that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation and the examples. I have learned a lot.